# Customizing a Jekyll theme does not include files included in the frontmatter from the gem

Tags: jekyll, yaml-front-matter, jekyll-theme

(Disclaimer: Jekyll noob here - using version 3.5.2)

I am trying to customize a Jekyll gem-based [theme](https://github.com/yizeng/jekyll-theme-simple-texture). I am aware that in order to do this I have to locate the files I want to overwrite (`bundle show theme-name`), copy them locally and then edit them. Now, whenever this file is requested, Jekyll will look first locally and then on the gem files. My problem is that Jekyll doesn't seem to do it for the files that are included in the frontmatter of other files.

To explain here is my non-working [structure](https://github.com/spygi/tech-blog/commit/5dea60118d07330ef48267c5546ae07f8b5bdedf):

```
gem theme/ 
|- _layouts/
   |- blog.html (has all the .css)
   |- page.html (has "layout: blog" in the frontmatter) 
   |- post.html (has "layout: blog") <- THIS is what I want to edit
   |- etc...

local jekyll_app/
|- index.html (has "layout: page")
|- _layouts/
   |- post.html (overwritten with my changes - works)
```

When I serve this: first I get a build warning about missing layout 'page'. Why doesn't Jekyll search in the gem folder? After adding only `page.html` locally, no build warning but nothing from `blog.html` is inserted in `_site/index.html` (eg. no CSS is requested at all).

Researching I found [this](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4246) which has to do with metadata only. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Impossible to reproduce this behavior. Did you have a repository url for this non working code ?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this @DavidJacquel, yes try to build this commit: https://github.com/spygi/tech-blog/commit/5dea60118d07330ef48267c5546ae07f8b5bdedf  
I added some more explanations in the question.

Comment: Sorry cannot reproduce your problem. `_layouts/blog.html` loads perfectly from the gem and css is loading.